# Differential of $0$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

If I have a $1$-form that in local coordinates can be written as $\alpha=\alpha_i dx^i$ and a vector field $X=\xi^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$, if I apply $\alpha$ to $X$ I should obtain the following:

$$\alpha(X)=\alpha_idx^i\Bigl(\xi^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Bigr)=\color{red}{\alpha_i\xi^j dx^i\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Bigr)}=\alpha_i\xi^j\delta^j_i=\alpha_i\xi^i$$
$\textbf{My question:}$ I can't understand the red expression, in particular why $\alpha_i dx^i\bigl(\xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\bigr)=\alpha_i\xi^j dx^i\bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\bigr)$; why can I put outside the $\xi^j$ (that is a $0$-form) outside the differential as it is a constant?

Comment: I think you mean to say "as it is NOT a constant" at the end?

Comment: Nope I have written as I intend: I am doing a comparison with the derivative for instance of real function $\frac{d}{dx}(af(x))=a\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$

Comment: Because $\mathrm{d}x^i$ is a linear form, and $\xi^j$ is a scalar.

Comment: @Didier $ \xi^j$ is not a function?

Comment: Well, it is a function of the basepoint $p \in M$, but in the tangent space $T_pM$, $\xi^i(p)$ is a just a constant (a scalar). And everything is pointwise.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha = \alpha_i \mathrm{d}x^i$ is a $1$-form and $X = X^j \partial_j$ is a vector field, the notation $\alpha(X)$ has to be understood as a function on $M$ defined by
$$\alpha(X)(p) = \alpha_p (X_p).$$
Now, for a fixed point $p \in M$, $\alpha_p$ is a linear form on $T_pM$ and $X_p = X^j(p) \partial_j(p)$ is a vector. Hence, by linearity
$$
\alpha(X)(p) = \alpha_i(p) \mathrm{d}x^i|_p\left(X^j(p)\partial_j(p) \right) = \alpha_i(p)X^j(p)\mathrm{d}x^i|_p \left(\partial_j(p) \right) = \alpha_i(p)X^j(p) \delta^i_j = \alpha_i(p)X^i(p).
$$
And this tells us that $\alpha(X)$ is the function on $M$
$$
\alpha(X) : p \mapsto \alpha_i(p)X^i(p).
$$

**Edit** Forget about the manifold. Suppose you have a vector space $V$ with basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ and dual basis of $V^*$ $(e^1,\ldots,e^n)$. Then if $X = X^i e_i \in V$ is a vector and if $\alpha = \alpha_j e^j \in V^*$ is a linear form on $V$, then by definition of the dual basis
$$
\alpha(X) = \alpha_iX^i.
$$
Now, remember that a tangent bundle $TM$ is a familly of vector spaces $(T_pM)_{p\in M}$. Do not think about any differentiable structure or anything. A vector field is a familly $(X_p)_{p\in M}$ with $X_p \in T_pM$. A $1$-form is a familly of covectors $(\alpha_p)_{p\in M}$ with $\alpha_p \in T_pM^*$.

Fix $p\in M$, apply the above reasoning to $V = T_pM$, $X = X_p$ and $\alpha = \alpha_p$.

**Comment** You seem to be confused about the differential. But the in the expression $\mathrm{d}x^i (X^j\partial_j)$, you are not taking any differential. You are just applying the $1$-form "$\mathrm{d}x^i$" to the vector $"X^j \partial_j"$.

Comment: Sorry maybe it is my fault: I can't understand...it is all right but it seems only exactly what I have written above not the specific answer to my question

Comment: @pawel I added an edit and a comment to precise the idea.

Comment: Thanks! So to be sure: the 0-form  is seen by the 1-form ($dx^i$) as a constant?

Comment: @pawel Yes. Because everything is pointwise. We can summarize that this way: a $1$-form is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-linear.